# Outlook 2010 and Windows 7 oversized font issues

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2010

On my home computer running Windows 7 x64 and Office 2010 x64 I've got a weird issue where my default font seems to have been changed / increased without me doing it. I've reset the default fonts on the system and it doesn't have any effect.

Here is a screen shot from Outlook 2010:

[image: Outlook Text Blown Up]

The font size appears to be blown up / larger than normal. In Chrome (I haven't taken a screen shot) the rendered font isn't blown up like in Outlook instead it seems to be a different font entirely.

I found this somewhat similiar issue: [Outlook 2007 font sizes](https://superuser.com/questions/147869/outlook-2007-font-sizes) only they method used to resolve it (permissions on the font folder) for this question doesn't seem to work for Windows 7.

This problem appears in other applications like VMware Workstation, Chrome which makes me thing its related to Windows and maybe a permissions problem with the font.

Any ideas?
 - know which fonts these use?

Comment: At the very bottom of this thread there is someone with the same problem: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistadesktopui/thread/c529a98b-731b-485a-8311-514623d98880

Answer (score 1):

It looks like somebody changed the default fonts used for menus. Please try the following:

1. Go back to your desktop (or right-click on the taskbar and select *Show the desktop*
2. Right-click anywhere on the desktop and select *Personalize*
3. Click on the *Window Color* link
4. Click on the *Advanced appearance settings...* link
5. You should now have a menu named *Window Color and Appearance*. Change the **Item** section there to *Message Box*. What is it set to?

[image: screenshot of Window Color and Appearance menu]

If it's set to something like "MS Sans Serif", you can change it to "Segoe UI", which is the default one for Windows 7.

Comment: It's already set to Segoe UI size 9.

Comment: When you go to *Control Panel* > *Display* and click on "Set custom text size (DPI)", what is it set to?

Comment: Smaller 100% default.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with default settings because I've reset them already.

Comment: @ckenst: It looks like the thread you posted (on the question) has the answer you're looking for. Changing the LogPixels setting from 96 to 92 (decimal) in the registry made my Outlook 2010 look the same as your screenshot. Could you try changing it back to 96 and see if it improves things?

Comment: Unfortunately that change has no effect. I wonder if there is a way to identify what fonts an application is using for a particular window?

Comment: @ckenst: Try making the LogPixels setting change then restart the machine.

Comment: That's how I did it because it was a registry edit I made the LogPixels change and restarted. Nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I've run out of ideas for this one. I'll continue looking for posts related to this issue, but for now let's wait for other responses.